# Retrieve Row Index From DataView using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, formatting, dataview

My DataView's Table attribute is assigned to one of my DataTables. The DataView is then set as my DataGridView's DataSource. Like so:

```
View.Table = DataSet1.Tables("dtArticles")
dgvArticles.DataSource = View
```

My goal is to perform some formatting on some given rows. Unfortunately, the only way I've found to do so is using the CellFormatting event. This is quite long since it must go through each row and verify if the row needs some formatting (bold font, backcolor).

**CellFormatting**

```
Private Sub dgvArticles_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvArticles.CellFormatting
    Dim drv As DataRowView
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex <= DataSet1.Tables("dtArticles").Rows.Count - 1 Then
            drv = View.Item(e.RowIndex)
            Dim c As Color

            'Bolds if it is standard, makes it regular if it's not standard and already bold
            If drv.Item("Standard").ToString = "Yes" Then
                dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Sherif", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
            End If

            'Test if Standard is "No" and if the row is currently bold, if it is, put it back to regular
            If drv.Item("Standard").ToString = "No" And Not dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font Is Nothing Then
                If dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font.Bold Then
                    dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Sherif", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
                End If
            End If

            'Puts a red color to the rows who are not available
            If drv.Item("Available").ToString = "No" Then
                'Change back color
                c = Color.LightSalmon
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = c
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What this does is for each row's cells added to the DataGridView; it checks if my `Standard` column's current value is equal to Yes or No. Depending on the result, it will bold / un bold the row. The same principal goes for my `Available` column. If the Available value is equal to "No" then I put a light red back color to the row. This event is raised many times (10,000 articles with a DataTable of 10 or so columns).

**About 2.2-2.7 seconds on average**

---

**Iterating through the DataView**

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each dt As BillMat.dtArticlesRow In View.Table.Rows
    If dt.Standard = "Oui" Then dgvArticles.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Sherif", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
    If dt.Available = "Non" Then dgvArticles.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
    i += 1
Next
```

**About 1.5-1.7 seconds on average**

---

Is it possible to use LINQ to select the RowIndex of which `Standard` column is equal to "Yes" and which `Available` column is equal to "No" ? If it is, wouldn't using the index to apply the formatting be much quicker than iterating through the whole 10,000 articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if using Link is the best solution for your problem.

You should first try to simplify the code in `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event. Some possibles ways:

- Create **one** private instance of regular and bold **Font** to avoid to create multiples instance in the method
- I guess you don't need to test the second condition if first is passed. So `If End If` + `If End If` could be replaced to `If Else End If` (don't need to test the two expressions)
- Use `If x AndAlso y Then` instead of `If x And y Then` : if first expression is false, the second won't be tested
- I don't understand the purpose of this `If e.RowIndex <= DataSet1.Tables("dtArticles").Rows.Count - 1 Then`. If the goal is not test if the row is the *NewRow* (with `AllowUserToAddRows` property set to True), simplier would be this

  ```
  If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow then
  ```

---

```
Private _RegularFont As New Font("Microsoft Sans Sherif", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
Private _BoldFont As New Font("Microsoft Sans Sherif", 8, FontStyle.Bold)

Private Sub dgvArticles_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvArticles.CellFormatting
    Dim drv As DataRowView
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If Not dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
            drv = View.Item(e.RowIndex)

            'Bolds if it is standard, makes it regular if it's not standard and already bold
            If drv.Item("Standard").ToString = "Yes" Then
                dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = _BoldFont
            Else 'First condition tested, test second 

                'Test if Standard is "No" and if the row is currently bold, if it is, put it back to regular
                If drv.Item("Standard").ToString = "No" AndAlso Not dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font Is Nothing Then
                    If dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font.Bold Then
                        dgvArticles.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Font = _RegularFont
                    End If
                End If
            End If

            'Puts a red color to the rows who are not available
            If drv.Item("Available").ToString = "No" Then
                'Change back color
                Dim c As Color
                c = Color.LightSalmon
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = c
            End If
        End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

---

Using link, you could do something like this (for your purpose, you should not iterate into `DataView.Rows` to retrieve index, but directly in `DataGridView.Rows`):

```
Dim _BoldFont As New Font("Microsoft Sans Sherif", 8, FontStyle.Regular)

Dim q = From r In Me.DataGridView1.Rows 
        Where CType(r, DataGridViewRow).Cells("Standard").Value.ToString = "Oui" 
        Select r
For Each item In q
        CType(item, DataGridViewRow).DefaultCellStyle.Font = _BoldFont
Next

Dim q = From r In Me.DataGridView1.Rows 
        Where CType(r, DataGridViewRow).Cells("Available").Value.ToString = "Non" 
        Select r
For Each item In q
        CType(item, DataGridViewRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured something quite alarming. Bolding a row is much more time consuming than changing it's row color. So I've switched it up a bit and started using row colors (1 bolded row takes about .3 seconds ... which is quite a lot). Also, when I go through my DataView it is already in memory which makes it quicker than the DataGridView Cell Formatting. In any case, the code pasted for the Cell formatting was gotten from another site and I didn't build it completely. Once again, thanks for the reply - appreciated.

Comment: @Alex You are welcome. I forgot to insert the font in my code - Fixed. Does it change anything?

Comment: I tested your solution and it is slightly faster (approximately 20 milliseconds on average) than my previous Cell Formatting. Although, the DataView solution is nearly 1 second faster. I initially wanted to use LINQ to avoid re-iterating through the DataView ... But I'm not sure how to do so, yet. If I figure it out I'll post the answer. Thanks Chris

Comment: By the way ... Why is it better to go through the DataGridView Rows instead of the DataView rows? I was wondering ...

Comment: @Alex Because it supposes they are in the same order and from my opinion not necessary, since the goal is to retrieve the row. But you could do some tests :)